# How to setup a site application on WLAN

Tags: database, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, wifi

I'm very new to setting up databases so please bear with me.

My application(MVC4 with Entity Framework) is has been running locally in IIS Express on my development computer. I was wondering if someone connected in my WLAN network can access it by typing in localhost:XXXXX on their chrome?

I don't need my site on the internet! I just want it to be able to be accessed by people in my WLAN network

Do I need to pay for some kind of database service ? If so can someone link me to one.

Can someone list options for me please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I was wondering if someone connected in my WLAN network can access it
>   by typing in localhost:XXXXX on their chrome?

No, `localhost` is the address for the local machine. So if someone types `localhost:XXXX` in a browser on their machine, it would point to IIS Express running (if any) on their machine.

If you want someone in your network access the website running on your computer, you can simply deploy it in IIS running on your machine. Then they could type in your computer's IP address (or name) and access your website provided your machine is turned on and IIS related services are running on your machine :).

Comment: How do you "deploy it in IIS running on your machine"? Is it possible to name it instead of having IP addresses typed in a browser?

Comment: If you search for "deploy asp.net application in IIS", I am sure you will find a number of links. Depending on your OS/IIS Version, please read through appropriate link. Regarding the possibility to use the name, I am sure it is. Again, you would just need to search for right things :). HTH.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions.